# error while making request to an asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I am making a request to an ASMX web service as follows -

```
private HttpWebResponse SendSoap12Msg(string url, string method, 
                       Dictionary<string, string> KeyValue)
{
    StringBuilder SoapMessage = new StringBuilder();
    SoapMessage.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
    SoapMessage.Append(@"<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'");
    SoapMessage.Append(@" xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>");
    SoapMessage.Append(@" xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'");
    //SoapMessage.Append(@" xmlns:soap12='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/'");
    SoapMessage.Append("<soap12:Body>");
    SoapMessage.Append("<");
    SoapMessage.Append(method);
    SoapMessage.Append(@" xmlns='http://tempurl.org/'>");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in KeyValue)
    {
        SoapMessage.Append("<");
        SoapMessage.Append(kvp.Key);
        SoapMessage.Append(">");
        SoapMessage.Append(kvp.Value);
        SoapMessage.Append("</");
        SoapMessage.Append(kvp.Key);
        SoapMessage.Append(">");
    }
    SoapMessage.Append("</");
    SoapMessage.Append(method);
    SoapMessage.Append(">");
    SoapMessage.Append("</soap12:Body>");
    SoapMessage.Append("</soap12:Envelope>");

    // Build HttpWebRequest
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"";
    //request.Accept = "application/soap+xml";

    // Send SOAP Envelope
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SoapMessage.ToString());
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    return (HttpWebResponse ) request.GetResponse();
}
```

However, whenever the request is sent, I am getting a `500 - Internal Server Error` as a response. Digging deeper into the exception, using these -

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    Response.Write("---------- Start: A WebException occured ----------<br />");
    Response.Write("Returned Content Type: " + ex.Response.ContentType); 
    Response.Write("<br />");
    Response.Write("Is From Cache: " + ex.Response.IsFromCache);
    Response.Write("<br />");
    Response.Write("Response URI: " + ex.Response.ResponseUri.ToString());
    Response.Write("<br />");
    Response.Write("ToString: " + ex.Response.ToString());
    Response.Write("<br />");
    Response.Write("ReadToEnd: " + 
            new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()); 
    Response.Write("<br />");
    Response.Write("---------- End: A WebException occured ----------");
}
```

I get the following output -

```
---------- Start: A WebException occured ----------
Returned Content Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Is From Cache: False
Response URI: (the target uri, as expected)
ToString: System.Net.HttpWebResponse
ReadToEnd: soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> 'soap12' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 40.
---------- End: A WebException occured ----------
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: A side question but: you are making a request to an ASMX webservice, but you aren't using it's WSDL to build the request? Why not? Typically these kind of errors are completely avoidable if you use the WSDL (provided the problem lies with the Request, not the service itself).

Comment: @Cloud: I don't understand what you meant. If you want to know why I am doing this way, it's because my client will be a generic clients for a lot of web services. It's actually working as a proxy. It will be given a web service address, method name and arguments as query parameter. It will then make a request to that method, using those arguments. I am fetching the WSDL though, before I make request. Is there a way to build up SOAP Envelope by reading WSDL?

Comment: With that explanation I can understand why you build the SOAP request yourself. You can ignore my comment in that regard.

Comment: You would do better to use "Add Service Reference" for all of the services that you need to reference, then using Reflection to find the generated classes and methods, and to pass the parameters to them. I have never found it useful to have such a "generic proxy". How do you test it? Generically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see missing from the SOAP request you are building is the `<request>` tag after the method name and before the parameters. Omitting it will sometimes produce errors like this, or make the translation of the request to the WS entities fail.

Try the following (omitted some things for brevity):

```
SoapMessage.Append(String.Format(@"<{0} xmlns='http://tempurl.org/'>", method));
SoapMessage.Append("<request>");    // Line added

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in KeyValue)
{
    SoapMessage.Append(String.Format("<{0}>", kvp.Key));
    SoapMessage.Append(kvp.Value);
    SoapMessage.Append(String.Format("</{0}>", kvp.Key));
}

SoapMessage.Append("</request>");   // Line added
SoapMessage.Append(String.Format("</{0}>", method));
```

Coincidently I came across this problem with a client of ours, and the missing request-tag was the cause. In some cases you can safely omit it, but sometimes it's mandatory apparently. I also added the use of `String.Format`, which makes the code shorter and easier to understand.

**Edit:**
The only other thing I see missing is you setting the [SOAP action](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) in the request header. You can add it in the following manner:

```
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction:", "http://tempurl.org/YourMethodname"); 
// You might need to try some variations. 
// Or replacing tempurl.org with the actual domain.
```

If you google for "C# HttpWebRequest SoapAction" your will find a lot more people getting Error 500; especially when omitting it in the request.

See also, this blog entry which is doing almost exactly the same thing as you are trying: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.nl/2006/05/making-raw-web-service-calls-with.html

Comment: +1 for the `String.Format` part, but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Dang, but I knew it was a long shot; these kinds of issues are difficult to resolve. I have added another thing you can try though, because I see you are missing the SOAPAction from the HTTP-Headers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the bindings for SOAP1.2 have been added to the web.config and they are configured for that service and enabled.

```
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoap12" type="tns:ServiceSoap">
```

and then

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap12"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Should these be added in the webservice's `web.config` or the client's `web.config` ?

Comment: and the first one (`wsdl:binding`) should go under `<system.web>`?